# Using the Java Spring Boot Framework to subscribe to STOMP messages

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, stomp

I am attempting to write a Spring service which subscribes to an external read only STOMP broker and read/process the messages it publishes.

The messages are pushed to the topic "/topic/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC" by a rail company. I can successfully connect to the topic, but can't seem to be able to instantiate a listener to its messages.

I have set up a Spring @Configuration class to connect to this and after running the application it appears to connect correctly.

I've also created the message handling routine, using the @MessageMapping annotation to listen to the particular topic I'm interested in ("TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC"). The problem is that it never seems to get called.

Configuration Class code:`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
                .setRelayHost("datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk")
                .setRelayPort(61618)
                .setSystemLogin("MYEMAIL")
                .setSystemPasscode("MYPASSWORD")
        ;
    }
}
```

Message handler code:

```
@MessageMapping("/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC")
public void onMessage(@Payload String message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

The following log entry is output to the console, indicating that the connection was successful.

> o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[TcpClient: connecting to datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk:61618] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

The message never gets printed however. I have been trying to get to the bottom of this one for a few days now so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The messages are pushed to the topic "/topic/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC" by a rail company. I can successfully connect to the topic, but can't seem to be able to instantiate a listener to its messages.

You mean a listener on client side, for example a sockjs client?

```
@MessageMapping("/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC")
public void onMessage(@Payload String message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

You do not return anything, you need to send it to a topic like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC")
@SendTo("/topic/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC")
public Greeting onMessage(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    return new Greeting("hello");
}
```

Or if your constructor has a SimpMessageSendingOperations in its parameters (should be autoWired by spring boot itself) you can send mutiple messages to the same topic like this:

```
@Autowired
public Constructor(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate) {
    this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
}

@MessageMapping(WebSockets.READER_MAPPING)
public void streamOverWebsocket(HelloMessage message) throws Throwable {
    String topicUrl = "/topic/TRAIN_MVT_ALL_TOC";
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(topicUrl, new Message("response 1"));
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(topicUrl, new Message("response 2"));
    ...
}
```

it's also best to wrap you incoming and outgoing in a defined class. That way it's easier to serialize and deserialize  it.

sources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageSendingOperations.html
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/